# Check status of process

Tags: c#, .net

I want to programmatically verify the status of an application to see if it has crashed or stopped. I know how to see if the process exists in C# but can I also see if it is "Not responding"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything you need is in System.Diagnostics, for example: to check if a process is responding.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessStatus
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Process Name: {0}, Responding: {1}", process.ProcessName, process.Responding);
            }

            Console.Write("press enter");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See ["Not Responding" Message in Windows Form Applicati](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/dotnetquestions/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=6167) at Fog Creek Software