# How to check if process is died or not from service

Tags: c#, winforms

From a C# service, how I can check whether another app is dead or not?

I tried to use Process.Responding, it returns true but the app is died.

[image]

This is the code:

```
private List<string> getListStringGAppPath()
    {
        List<string> listGAppPaths = new List<string>();
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApp");

        if (processes.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; i++) {
                listGAppPaths.Add(processes[i].Responding.ToString() + "@@@@@@" + processes[i].MainModule.FileName);
                //processes[i].Responding.ToString() always return True
            }
            return listGAppPaths;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If a process is not responding, because of being busy, it doesn't mean the process has exited.

Answer (score 0):

When process dies, windows seems to toggles its state to `Suspended`, you can try checking its state first. Also here: [Detecting process crash in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309836/detecting-process-crash-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods in `System.Diagnostics.Process` to get process information.

`GetProcessesByName(String)`

Creates an array of new Process components and associates them with all the process resources on the local computer that share the specified process name.

`GetProcessById(Int32)`

Returns a new Process component, given the identifier of a process on the local computer.

`GetProcesses()`

Creates a new Process component for each process resource on the local computer.

If the process does not exist, then it must have died?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the process is responding:

```
foreach (var process in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Process Name: {0}, Responding: {1}", process.ProcessName, process.Responding);
}
```

Similar to this answer:
[Check status of process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320645/check-status-of-process)